# How can I access a Virtual Machine on different subnet?

Tags: networking, centos, linux-networking, sonicwall

I have two virtual machine VMachineA and VMachineB using virtual box. VMachineA (CentOs 6.5) has two network interfaces:

1. eth0 (IP: `192.168.3.48`, GW: `192.168.3.1`) and
2. eth1 (IP: `10.10.200.1`).

VMachineA is working as a router, and portforwarding is enabled. In VMachineA `eth0` is bridged, and `eth1` is host only network. My machine's Ip address is `192.168.3.27`, its gateway is `192.168.3.1`.

VMachineB has centos one interface eth0 (`IP 10.10.200.2`, GW: `10.10.200.1`). In `192.168.3.1` it has a sonicwall firewall. So what rule(s) do I have to add in Sonicwall to access VMachineB from my LAN(like `192.168.3.10` machine)?

Comment: please have look on last few lines you will understand the problem.

Comment: For me it seems he *has* the needed minimal understanding. I formatted the message to be more understable - please consider changing your downvote, or/and vote for the reopening of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a route to 10.10.200.0/24 via 192.168.3.48 to sonicwall.

Comment: actually i am new to sonicwall. I have added some static routing in sonicwall but that doesn't work out. May i have link(or guidance) how to add a route in sonic wall.

Comment: Sorry, i don't have experience with Sonicwall. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: Help? Help? Here...? Now was this question closed by a hird a nonworking trolls defining themself as "community". Their probable real motive was that they also don't know sonicwall and so they hadn't chance to answer this question.

Comment: Found this:

http://help.mysonicwall.com/sw/eng/601/ui2/22200/Network/Routing.htm

Comment: Thanks @ThomasStinner for the link. [Here](http://asitm9.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-access-computer-on-different.html) is a brief description how i have solved the problem.